# Can an attorney-in-fact with full powers transfer his power to another entity? Please explain

Tags: trusts-and-estates, power-of-attorney

Say there is a Power of Attorney that grants full power to entity A. When I say full power, that means, anything that the original entity can do, it can also do. Now of course, I am not an attorney, but I dont know if entity A can create its own special power of attorney to grant entity B a full power.

In any circumstance, can entity A transfer his full power or grant his same power to another entity, which the original entity is not a signatory? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Power of Attorney cannot grant “full power”

A PoA grants rights to deal with a person’s assets and financial affairs only. It may be subject to conditions but even if it isn’t it is limited to only those sorts of matters. Granting PoA is not one of those sorts of matters.

Comment: oh w0w! That clears it. Thanks!